# Jenkins trigger installation script for new build only

Tags: jenkins, windows-10

I am building a new Jenkins job to install the package once a new build is ready.
If I set the Jenkins job run at every hour, how to avoid install the same build?

Example:
Build 1.139.506 just ready
Then Jenkins kins job trigger installation for build 1.139.506
At next hour, Jenkins job is triggered again.

If build is still 1.139.506, then stop job, no installation needed.

Else, repeat step to install new build.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve what you need.

- Use an SCM repository and do polls on the repo. So Jenkins will only run the Job if the source code changes.
- Use an SCM and tag the source when you release a new version, in this case, you can run the Job if a new tag is created in the SCM.
- Save the last deployed version somewhere and check if the current version is different from the last deployed version.
- Check the deployment environment for the deployed version and check if the current version is different, if so run the Job, else skip.